# Software RIP must be able to read or recognize color information in PDF

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I use a printer from ROLAND and its software RIP "VersaWorks Dual". The RIP must be able to recognize or read the color information / layers so that it is possible to correct color values.

When I create the PDF (from a PS file) with Acrobat Distiller and set the Distiller parameter "/ColorConversionStrategy /LeaveColorUnchanged" the color information can be read.
But I want to use GhostScript and the color information cannot be recognized if created with GhostScript.

I tried several settings (-sColorConversionStrategy=/LeaveColorUnchanged, -dAutoFilterColorImages=false, -dAutoFilterGrayImages=false, -dPreserveHalftoneInfo=true) but without any positive result.

Has anybody an idea?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like something you need to take up with the supplier of the RIP software, presumably ROLAND.

Howwever, clearly there is still **some** colour information which the RIP can read, you would get an error or wildly incorrect output if the colour information had been discarded or corrupted.

Therefore it seems likely to me that the colour information is still present, but may have been 'altered' in some way. In general however, the Ghostscript pdfwrite device goes to some considerable lengths to retain colour unaltered unless you specifically tell it not to.

If you make an example PostScript file available, and state the exact Ghostscript command line used, Ghostscript version and operating system I can take a look at it.

Since you clearly have a working solution with Acrobat Distiller, why do you want to use Ghostscript anyway ?

Comment: Hi KenS, Thank you for your answer.

I agree, I had contact to ROLAND. Unfortunately they don't want or cannot help.

I want to use Ghostscript because of the costs. It will be used at several stations.
I tried it with version 9.22 and the command: gswin64c -q -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dColorConversionStrategy=/LeaveColorUnchanged -sOutputFile=C:\temp\PsExample.pdf C:\temp\PsExample.ps

Comment: I can't tell you anything more without an example file to look at. How do you know that "the colour information cannot be recognised" ?

Comment: I would like to give you an example but I don't know / can't see how to attach or send. Am I too stupid? Please don't laugh.

Comment: Just put it somewhere public and put a URL here. Dropbox or something will be fine.

Comment: Here's the example PS file:
https://wika.sharefile.eu/d-s6bebb4b7d9a48618
Thank you.

Comment: Well, looking at the output from Ghostscript's pdfwrite device, the file only contains RGB colours. When I run the file through Adobe Acrobat Distiller, the colour space depends on the settings I select, but the original PostScript file sets all its colours in RGB space, and they are the same as the Ghostscript output. Using Distiller's settings, and checking 'Leave colors unchanged' results in a PDF file which is, essentially, identical to the Ghostscript one produced from the simplest possible GS command line "gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=out.pdf <input.ps>".

Comment: So to be honest I can see no reason for your RIP to differentiate between the two. I think you're going to have to go back to Roland and insist they explain why their RIP isn't able to colour correct the Ghostscript output  Oh, you still hhaven't said how you know 'the colour information cannot be recognised'. Are you getting some kind of feedback./error from the RIP ?

Comment: There's no error message or similar ones.
The job settings has an option "File Format" where you can activate the recognization of special colors. That means, that the software reads the pdf RGB colors and can substitue them with "better" RGB values which fits
better to the printer. These color library is made by us.
The ghostscript pdf is not fully identified whereas the distiller pdf is.

Comment: OK so the explanation is useful, you have a simple RGB->CMYK conversion via a lookup. I'm not really sure what I'm looking at with the screenshots. If you are expecting to find some object in the PostScript/PDF fiel which has the specific RGB colour values of R=0, G = 165, B = 41 then your problem is that your colour specification matching is too precise.

Comment: PostScript doesn't use values from 0->255 for RGB colours, it uses values from 0->1. In your original PostScript file the colours are specified as 0.0000 0.6471 0.1608 and in the output from Ghostscript they are defined as 0 0.646484 0.160889. The difference is caused by rounding errors with floating point values and is about half a percent different. I'd have to guess that your matching library isn't doing any kind of tolerance with matching the values, so that's pretty much bound to give you problems. There's no way for you to do anything about this with Ghostscript.

Comment: Sometimes the floating point difference will even out so that when converted from 0->1 into 0->255 they match, sometimes it won't.

Comment: Ok, I understand the color code (0->1, 0->255) problem. But the tools and the way we use for creating the pdf files didn't change. They made a change in their software (VersaWorks Dual) and now we have trouble.
But anyway, thank you very much for your help and time you spent for my problem.